# Почему null считается нежелательным значением по умолчанию

Tags: mysql

Собственно, вот и вопрос. Почему null считается не очень хорошим значением для установки по умолчанию (default)? Кое-где встречал, что для timestamp пойдет, но лучше его вообще избегать. Так и не понял, почему?

Comment: Потому что для NULL нужно дополнительное место для хранения.

Comment: @Visman и тогда как быть? Что лучше использовать для дефолтного значения?

Comment: А вам обязательно нужно значение по умолчанию для поля?

Comment: @Visman да честно говоря, я без понятия :D Есть таблица, к примеру, сотрудников. Там их личная информация и некоторые поля могут быть незаполненными. Соответственно, нужно выбрать значение поумолчанию для того, чтобы потом делать проверку "есть значение или нет". Насколько сильно мне нужен этот дефолт, я понятия пока не имею. Впервые проектирую БД, не хочу ошибиться с этим, чтобы потом разгребать.

Comment: null стоит избегать не только в БД, но и в коде. вам придется везде добавлять проверку на null, так как многие конструкции воспринимаю null как ошибку. лучшим вариантом будет добавить "пустое" значение. например для текста подойдет пустая строка или строка вида "не указано"

Comment: @VostokSisters, вот например поле "о себе" - текстовое и если оно равно "", то явно не заполнено. Null тут не нужен. Какие там еще поля могут быть у сотрудника? Номер отдела - 0го отдела не может существовать.

Comment: Мои наблюдения, что если в столбце нету значения null, то выборка по индексированому полю таблицы значительно быстрее работает (mssql)

Comment: @Visman в текстовое поле вроде бы дефолт не прописывается вообще.

Comment: Да, перепутал с VARCHAR :)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman в большинстве случаев null является валидным значением (значением отсутствия) и требует куда меньше ресурсов для обработки, чем проектирование архитектуры с NullObject. если уж избавляться, то путем Optional и аналогов.

Comment: @etki я считаю, что потратить время на продумывание архитектуры - это хороший вариант. а что конкретно использовать - NullObject, Optional, etc, зависит от множества факторов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Null является некоторым исключением из правил, что порождает дополнительные сложности, но больше все-таки для разработчиков СУБД, нежели для ее пользователей - как отделить null-значения от обычных, не изменяя диапазон возможных значений, включать ли такие записи в индекс (и включать их в начало или в конец индекса), как оптимизировать запросы с null, в каких случаях null == null, а в каких нет. Это дает небольшую обратную связь конечному пользователю СУБД - например, в сети сложно найти однозначный ответ, включает ли MySQL null в индекс и у моих друзей был случай (отмечу, что далеко не вчерашний - за это время многое могло поменяться), когда запрос с обычной фильтрацией использовал индекс, а запрос с фильтрацией по null этот индекс не использовал (опять же это могло быть вызвано кривизной самого запроса - не берусь утверждать); в каких-то сложных запросах наверняка можно встретить отклонения от ожидаемого из-за неопределенности учета null (например, запрос `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE field NOT LIKE '%'` - в нем должны считаться null-записи, или нет?). Поэтому я считаю, что рекомендация не использовать null из-за каких-то ограничений хранилища - это скорее городская легенда, чем реальная проблема (и косвенно меня подтверждает выдача гугла, в которой нет подтверждений существования проблемы), просто при работе с null нужно проявлять повышенную осторожность и тщательней проверять гипотезы.

Что до "заменяйте null чем угодно, лишь бы не работать с null" - я с этим категорически не могу согласиться. В этом случае вы начинаете менять данные ради удобства хранилища, что инверсирует саму идею инструментария, который должен служить решаемым задачам, а не наоборот. Null - это абсолютно легальная форма значения, обозначающая отсутствие этого значения и ни в коем случае не являющая идентичной какому-то нейтральному значению. Можно представить следующий пример: есть проект с пользователями, у пользователей есть номера телефонов, по которым производится SMS-рассылка. Архитектор базы данных может подумать, что проще будет иметь дело с пустыми строками у тех пользователей, которые его не указали, нежели добавлять проверку на null, но на самом деле это не решит проблему, а только усложнит ее:

- При рассылке SMS проверка на null просто заменится проверкой на длину строки. Польза - нулевая, неинтуитивность работы приложения - повышается
- В случае, если телефоны записывались как с +7, так и без в начале, и это было решено исправить - нельзя просто добавить +7 всем записанным номерам, потому что пустые номера в этом случае превратятся в +7, и SMS-рассылка начнет слать SMS в никуда, а выяснится это уже только после того.

Подытоживая - данные *первичны*, если у вас что-то отсутствует, как утка, то и записывать надо отсутствие утки, потому что иначе есть риск сделать неправильную проверку на отсутствие.

Comment: Спасибо за широкое теоретическое пояснение, такого я и ждал)